# Android integration with Stripe

Tags: android, heroku, stripe-payments

I'm trying to integrate my Android app with Stripe. I've created an store and I would like to manage the checkout.
So, I'm trying to implement with Android Studio, VS Code and Heroku. On the backend side, I'm trying to create the backend side for preparing the payment.

This is my gradle file in Vs Code. I have added

```
implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:11.1.4'
```

And this is my heroku.java app

```
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import com.stripe.android.Stripe;

@Controller
@SpringBootApplication
public class HerokuApplication {

  @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
  private String dbUrl;

  @Autowired
  private DataSource dataSource;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(HerokuApplication.class, args);
  }

  @RequestMapping("/")
  String index() {
    return "index";
  }

  @RequestMapping("/fusion")
  String fusion(Map<String, Object> carro){
    // Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
Stripe.apiKey = "sk_test_9Y7kTvkOhZEcT8HnkHhkQuOC00krpQNDQR";

Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();

ArrayList<String> paymentMethodTypes = new ArrayList<>();
paymentMethodTypes.add("card");
params.put("payment_method_types", paymentMethodTypes);

ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> lineItems = new ArrayList<>();
HashMap<String, Object> lineItem = new HashMap<String, Object>();
lineItem.put("name", "T-shirt");
lineItem.put("description", "Comfortable cotton t-shirt");
lineItem.put("amount", 500);
lineItem.put("currency", "eur");
lineItem.put("quantity", 1);
lineItems.add(lineItem);
params.put("line_items", lineItems);

params.put("success_url", "https://example.com/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}");
params.put("cancel_url", "https://example.com/cancel");

Session session = Session.create(params);
return "carro";

  }
```

I'm trying to build the gradle with this error... and as you can see not much idea about Heroku and Stripe, so I don't know how to fix this error.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.

  > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
  >   Could not find com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0.
  >    Required by:
  >        project : > com.stripe:stripe-android:11.1.4
  >   Could not find androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0.
  >    Required by:
  >        project : > com.stripe:stripe-android:11.1.4
  >   Could not find androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0.
  >    Required by:
  >        project : > com.stripe:stripe-android:11.1.4
  >   Could not find androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0.
  >    Required by:
  >        project : > com.stripe:stripe-android:11.1.4

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to use stripe-android on your backend. You should be using [stripe-java](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java). Also, v11.x of stripe-android requires AndroidX.